# FactoryGirl, Rspec, and complex database structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

We have really big rails application and currently we are switching from TestUnit/fixtures to Rspec/FactoryGirl. Our database has a lot of "system" tables where data is either constant or updated rarely. For example

```
user_types
ID  NAME                       ...
1   System Adminisrator        ...
2   Organization Administrator ...
....
9   Mega Administrator         ...
```

In additional we have a lot of configuration tables and long references between them. For example:

```
master_organizations many-to-many organizations has_many 
plan_years has_many products has_many plans

organizations has_many employees ... and so on
```

And we need all system tables and at least one organization configured before all the specs run. And then each suite will be able to add additional data to db if needed.

So **the question is** how to build a nice, complex and flexible structure which is readable for a developer? Today the closest solution for us is to move db structure creation into separate files: create there shared_contexts for system tables, configuration tables and so on. And then include it if necessary. But not sure if this approach is good.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you have almost-constant data that will be present almost-always. In production, on your development machine, on each test run etc. Then you have data that changes; in production it's the data generated by your users, in tests you need to simulate it.

Now we just need to use the right tool for each job. Almost-constant data is what *seeds* are for, while simulating the changing data is where *factories* shine.

The seeds provided by Rails aren't that great, but can become immensely better thanks to a couple of gems.

[SeedFu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) gives you a nice DSL for defining seeds that won't be duplicated on subsequent runs. E.g.

```
User.seed_once(:email,
  { :email => "jon@example.com",   :name => "Jon"   },
  { :email => "emily@example.com", :name => "Emily" }
)
```

[Seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank) gives some well-needed structure to the seed files. It overrides the default `rake db:seed` task and provides environment-specific folders for seeds that aren't needed everywhere. So you'd have something like:

```
db/seeds/
  development/
    users.seeds.rb
  organizations.seeds.rb
  user_types.seeds.rb
```

This way, you don't need to have that many overlapping concepts (fixtures etc). Seeds handle the constant-ish data, factories handle mostly test-specific data. Hope it'll be of some use.

Note: It is of course better if your tests can be self-contained, with no dependencies on seeds or other database state. In reality though, some of your data is as integral a part of your app as the models around it. Our approach can bring with it a few headaches (always run seeds on migration, database cleaning strategies), but it's worked for us so far. Adapt the parts that fit your use case.